# Need to open latest PDF file from website daily with Python 2.7

Tags: python, html, pdf, beautifulsoup

I am writing a script that will open the latest file on a webpage every day. My code so far is as follows:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re


html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.baytown.org/city-hall/departments/police/daily-media-report")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': 
re.compile("^/home/showdocument")}):

       print link.get('href')
```

My output is

```
/home/showdocument?id=7455
/home/showdocument?id=7379
/home/showdocument?id=7381
/home/showdocument?id=7385
/home/showdocument?id=7385
/home/showdocument?id=7401
/home/showdocument?id=7451
/home/showdocument?id=7453
```

I need to read the latest file in this list (the highest id#) and Im stuck. How do I find the file with the highest number and read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added all the id numbers into a list and then sorted the list to get the highest id number.

Code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

pdfs = []
html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.baytown.org/city-hall/departments/police/daily-media-report")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/home/showdocument")}):
       pdfs.append(str(link.get('href')).split('id=')[1])
latest = sorted(pdfs)[-1]
print "Latest PDF id = ", latest
```

Output:

```
Latest PDF id =  7455
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the latest PDF is allways the first on the list:

```
latest = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/home/showdocument")})[0]["href"].split('=')[1]
print (latest)
```

Which outputs `7455`